# Applying Pro Guard on Android, ProGuard is not applied because no exception is handled

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In the code below, I want to resolve the error with the exception of ContextImpl. Please advise.

```
-dontwarn android.content.**
-keep class android.content.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.content.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.widget.**
-keep class android.widget.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.widget.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.view.**
-keep class android.view.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.view.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.app.ContextImpl.**
-keep class android.app.ContextImpl.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.app.ContextImpl.** { *; }

Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.ActivityThread
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.ApplicationPackageManager
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class             
android.app.ActivityThread
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.LoadedApk
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.ActivityThread
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.LoadedApk
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced class 
android.os.FileUtils
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced method 
'java.io.File[] buildExternalStorageAppFilesDirs(java.lang.String)' in 
 library class android.os.Environment
Warning:android.app.ContextImpl: can't find referenced method 
'java.io.File[] buildPaths(java.io.File[],java.lang.String[])' in library
```

Applying Pro Guard on Android, ProGuard is not applied because no exception is handled.

Other exceptions are handled, but ContextImpl is not the only exception.
The same error occurs after ContextImpl exception handling

Comment: Is there a question you wanted to ask?

Comment: sorry I am not good at English 
I want to resolve the error with the exception of ContextImpl